# Simple way to have a different stylesheet for mobile, screen, and print

Tags: css

I have one webpage that I want to pull different stylesheets for print, mobile, screen, etc.

I have screen and print working perfectly. I have two different stylesheets for mobile - one for modern smartphones (iPhone/Android), one for Blackberries. They're called mobile.css and blackberry.css respectively.

How can I simply have my page load the mobile stylesheet when iPhone/Android accesses the page, and the blackberry stylesheet when most Blackberries load the page?

Using `max-width: 480px` will work, but it will also force the mobile stylesheet upon a Blackberry (whose screen is also 480px wide), which is undesired behavior.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

For Printing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print">
```

For targetting the Blackberry specifically, you may have to do some `User-Agent` sniffing.